# python xmpp wokkel JID escaping

Tags: python, xmpp, wokkel

After a painful search for Python XMPP library to use for XEP 060 I finally decided on wokkel and twisted.

However, they cannot understand the simple JID escaping of XEP-106

I am trying to pass username as an email address so I escape it  like this
admin\40local.domain@mydomain.tldr
where the username is admin@local.domain

The program complains about invalid character in username
Should I try another library that does work? and has documentation. I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a guess, but if you have the username or JID in a string, and are specifying it like:

```
"admin\40local.domain@mydomain.tld"
```

If so, Python treats backslash [escape codes](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) specially. Change it to a double backslash to actually insert a single backslash into the string:

```
"admin\\40local.domain@mydomain.tld"
```

Comment: makes sense. will try in awhile.